# AngularJS 2 localization service best practice

Tags: angularjs, angular, localization

I have a service, in which I can call:

`localization('navbar.home')`

And it returns 'Home'.

A few questions:

1. At the moment, I have to inject this service to every component I work with, and then I write `let lang = localization;`, Is there a way to bind it into something like NG1 `$rootScope`, so I'll have to load it once?
2. Is there a way to one time bind the function? NG1 gave me the option to write: `{{::lang('navbar.home')}}`, so it was only called once.

---

My attitude for localization may be totally outdated, or wrong, because I am migrating from NG1.

What is the best practice here? Keep it as a service? Not bind it once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injected services are inherited, you can inject them just once at root level (bootstrap) if you wish to use them in all components:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
/* everything you put here is available  in all components */ 
  ServiceOne,
  ServiceTwo
])
```

You'll still need to declare them in your components' constructor:

```
constructor(private so: ServiceOne) {}
```

but you don't include them in `providers[]` metadata of the component.

Can't help with other stuff (;